# PostgreSQL: could not connect to server - Connection refused error

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection, database-server

I've failed to set up `postgreSQL` to work with my `Ruby-on-Rails` project for the past week. 
I've tried to uninstall and reinstall, `postgreSQL`, twice now.
But when I try to launch `postgreSQL` I keep getting the error below:

```sql
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
         Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and
         accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? 
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) 
         Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and 
         accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"
```

I've looked at many online resources, including *stackoverflow* and none seem helpful.
The key parts of my `pg_hba.conf` file looks like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

And the key part of my `postgresql.conf` file is as follows:

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directories = ''   # comma-separated list of directories
                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
```

Most of the suggestions, I've seen so far, were based on those two files. (For my case, they were already configured correctly). I also tried disabling the firewall and restarting postgreSQL but it didn't help. Does anyone have any suggestions for me? Thanks!

Comment: are you on the same pc as the db server? If not you need setup firewall

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same PC as the db server. How do I setup firewall? I've tried disabling it as well as enabling the postgres app on windows firewall.

Comment: Firewall only is an issue if you are in a different pc. Can you connect using `pgAdmin`? Check the service is up and you are using the right port

Comment: I tried connecting using pgAdmin, it was running the same error as above. The port # is correct an matches across all files.

Comment: check the services to see if is running. First install should be very easy. I suggest you try another pc.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be running. it's refusing my connection with the same error as above after trying to login with the correct password. I don't have access to another PC to try and download it. I was just hoping it was an issue I could solve by changing the config file around.

Comment: But is service running? Try to start it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wGSw.png

Comment: Services is not running. When I tried to start service it gave me an Error 5: Access is denied .

Comment: That is very weirds, maybe you wrote the wrong password? I would try reinstalling postgres again. You can run multiple servers just assign a different port and install folder.

Comment: Im redownloading now and will assign the port to 5433 as opposed to 5432 and will install under a different folder. Hopefully this resolves the issue.

Comment: I've reinstalled, there was an error that I've experienced everytime aside from the first time downloading that I forgot to mention. A popup window states " Problem installing post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly.  Failed to start the database server." Is this part of the issue as well?

Comment: Yes, looks like you cant install it, do you have administrator privilege?

Comment: Yes, I am the owner of the PC and have permission.

Comment: You shouldnt need it, but try right click over install file and select run as administrator.

Comment: Just ran as administrator but received the same error upon install completion.  It still lets me finish install and the data/files have been installed. The server just isn't running.

Comment: Then you have to investigate about that error. May I suggest create a virtual pc  https://www.virtualbox.org/ is easy setup to have an empty pc?

Comment: I downloaded the software. What exactly do I  have to do with virtual pc?

Comment: Just create a virtual pc, install windows, download postgre and try to install it. Install postgres should be very easy in a virgin pc. Just next next.

Answer (score 8):

Got the same issue while settings up PostgreSQL 9.6.16 to work with Python/Django, but this is purely a database issue.

> **The solution lies in the error:** In fact, I found this error mentioned within the official [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/server-start.html#CLIENT-CONNECTION-PROBLEMS) thus it's a common error.

And here is how I resolved this issue:

1. Always **first** start the postgres [database server](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/server-start.html), use `postgres` or the wrapper program `pg_ctl`.
   I used the command, below, on `windows 10`.
   Remember, whatever comes after `-D` should be the path to where you installed PostgreSQL, to the `data` folder, which holds the `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` files.

```
> pg_ctl start -D "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data"
```

2. If that runs well, you are **ready** to [access](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/tutorial-accessdb.html) the database server.
   Open another `cmd` shell, and type the command below.
   Remember the password you entered while installing `PostgreSQL`?
   Enter that password when asked `Password for user postgres:`

```
> psql -U postgres
```

Once done, you can now go ahead to `CREATE ROLE` and `CREATE DATABASE` accordingly.

Comment: where to run these commands? SQL shell? Windows CMD? what is "wrapper program pg_ctl" ??

Comment: Hi, @nishi. Yes, the sign `>` means you comfortably run this in windows `cmd`. And true, `pg_ctl` is a wrapper/utility program to help you run a couple of tasks on the `PostgreSQL` server. [Here's a good read on that](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pg-ctl.html)

Comment: thanks @MwamiTovi. well, the problem when I was trying to run this command was cuz not always the psql command is set in the windows environment path. I solved the issue by editing the postgres server. Mine was on port 5433 and i my db was sending info on 5432 if it helps any further readers. but i still cant run pg_ctl on my cmd.