# PostgreSQL: Could not connect to server: TCP/IP connections on port 5432

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, database-server

I have an error with PostgreSQL:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7]  could not connect to server: Connection refused
>           Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and 
>           accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused 
>           Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and  accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

The following command doesn't show 5432 port is open:

```
sudo netstat -plunt |grep postgres
```

I guess that the problem is 5432 port so as I don't see it at `netstat`.
 How to open port for PostgreSQL?

1. The `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` files are okay (see below).
2. `postgres` server is running
3. My `postgresql.conf` file:

```sql
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

4. My `pg_hba.conf` file:

```sql
local   all             postgres                                md5
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

3. I ran the command: `$ netstat -atu`

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 localhost:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:http            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:https           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 30secondboomer.com:ssh  109-252-90-59.nat:11807 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 30secondboomer.com:ssh  109-252-90-59.nat:11258 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 30secondboomer.com:ssh  109-252-90-59.nat:11797 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 localhost:6379          [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*                  LISTEN
udp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 30secondboomer.c:bootpc 0.0.0.0:*
```

Comment: Please check the logs. The PostgreSQL server obviously (netstat output) is not running.

Comment: I use command "sudo service postgresql status"        ● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2019-03-24 21:01:12 MSK; 6min ago
  Process: 24974 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 24974 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 24 21:01:12 cs451508 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Mar 24 21:01:12 cs451508 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.

Comment: Localhost should be open to itself. Are you trying to jump between servers on that port? Or are you connecting on same server to the database?

Comment: On the same server

Comment: It seems that server is not  running. Below is PostgreSQL log: FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "109.252.90.59"
LOG:  received fast shutdown request
LOG:  aborting any active transactions
LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 421) exited with exit code 1
LOG:  shutting down

Comment: LOG:  database system is shut down  pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
FATAL:  could not remove old lock file "postmaster.pid": Permission denied
HINT:  The file seems accidentally left over, but it could not be removed. Please remove the file by ha$
pg_ctl: could not start server

Comment: @АндрейПисарев: `postgresql.service` is an umbrella service whose status does not prove anything. The actual service is probably `postgresql@11-main`. You may have multiple instances of postgres managed by systemd depending on your OS.

Comment: I have only one instance and log above from postgresql-11-main.log

Comment: I run command "service postgresql@11-main status" and got
● postgresql@11-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Sun 2019-03-24 21:23:14 MSK; 16min ago
  Process: 329 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 11-main start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.

Comment: Before that I ran command "service postgresql restart", "service postgresql stop", "service postgresql start"

Comment: I found an answer by grant rigths "chmod u+w /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/"

Comment: Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74163070/14591547

Answer (score 3):

Got a similar error while settings up `PostgreSQL` to work with a `Python/Django` project.

1. Try to `stop` and `restart` the server again.
2. If indeed the challenge is port `5432` as you suspect, you can try to `start postgres` on another port say `5433` and see what happens.
3. For those, whose `database server` is not running at all, this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59033144/10849438) worked for me, after reading the official `PostgreSQL-9.6.16` documentation.

Answer (score -2):

In your pg_hba.conf, you have :

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

But this should probably contain the actual IP address of the machine from which the requests are coming (even if it is localhost, it should still contain the remote IP address as a connection from another machine would refer to it.