# PostgreSQL server Connection error: could not connect to server

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, postgresql-11

I am using `pgAdmin4` and developing a `node.js` app.
I had an abrupt shutdown of the computer and I can no longer connect to the `postgresql` server.

The error I get when trying to connect is :

```sql
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
             Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and 
             accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
      could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
             Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and 
             accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried to run `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres/` as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307346/is-the-server-running-on-host-localhost-1-and-accepting-tcp-ip-connections).
 However it gave me the following error :

```sql
postgres: could not access directory "usr/loval/var/postgres": No such file or directory
Run initdb or pg_basebackup to initialize a PostgreSQL data directory.
```

So I just manually deleted the `postmaster.pid` file inside the `PostgreSQL/.../data` folder. 
But I still cannot connect to the database server.

I have checked the `postgresql.conf` file, and 
the listen addresses is already set as `listen_addresses = '*'`, and the port is set to `5432`.

I also tried deleting the pgAdmin file in the AppData/Roaming folder.
But it gave me an error:

```sql
The application server could not be contacted
```

and then afterwards the same problem of not being able to connect to the server happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny enough, it was a matter of just deleting the pdAdmin file in AppData/Roaming folder, and then restarting the computer and restarting the pgAdmin4.  That solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Meet the same challenge while settings up `PostgreSQL` to work with a `Python/Django` project.
And i [resolved the issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59033144/10849438), after reading the official `PostgreSQL-9.6.16` documentation.